# Getting dynamic file in Spring Integration flow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

How to configure the dynamic file name in Spring Integration flow?

Scenario: On FTP, every day file get generated for current date. Through the SFTP, need to read current date file.
Example: *_20220525_DATA.TXT, *_20220526_DATA.TXT

Answer (score 0):

Why just `patternFilter("*_DATA.TXT")` doesn't work for you?

The `SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter` cannot be modified for its pattern.

Although you can implement a custom `FileListFilter` to have its patterns to be changed every day.

Comment: Created IntegrationFlows.from with filter(remoteFtr()) and localFilter(LocalFtr())
remoteFtr: new ChainFileListFilter<LsEntry>().addFilters( new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(RegexFtr()), new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "TEST"));
LocalFtr: new ChainFileListFilter<File>().addFilters( new RegexPatternFileListFilter(RegexFtr()), new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
RegexFtr: Pattern.compile("^TEST[0-9]{2}_[A-Z0-9_]{7}"+LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"))+"[0-9]+_DATA\\.(TXT)$");

Comment: cron exp: 0 0 13-18 * * ? 
Code snippet attached. 1st time its reading the correct file but next day scheduler is not reading file.

Comment: Sorry, the code in the comment is not readable. Please, consider to edit your question with that info.

Comment: He asked same question again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72455894/spring-integration-flow-get-dynamic-file-based-on-current-date