# Spring Integration flow: Get dynamic file based on current date

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

How should update filter, so that everyday it will gets updated?

CronExpression : 0 0 13-18 * * ? which polls everyday in afternoon

Code snippet attached. When the application start at 1st time, its reading the correct file but next day scheduler does not read the current date file

Example : 1st day file: TEST_20220530_DATA.TXT - flow pick up this file

2nd Day file: TEST_20220531_DATA.TXT - next day, when it start polling does not read this file

```html
 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {     
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(sessionFactory())
                        .remoteDirectory(ftpProperty.getRemotePath())
                        .filter(buildRemoteFileFilter())
                        .maxFetchSize(ftpProperty.getFetchSize())
                        .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
                        .preserveTimestamp(true)
                        .localDirectory(Paths.get(ftpProperty.getDownloadPath()).toFile())
                        .autoCreateLocalDirectory(false)
                        .localFilter(buildLocalFileFilter()),
                p -> p.poller(Pollers.cron(ftpProperty.getReadT1CronExpression()) //0 0 13-18 * * ? which polls everyday in afternoon
                        .errorChannel("errorChannel").advice()))
                .handle(new ServiceActivatingHandler(testActivatorService, "process"))
                .get();
    }
    
    private CompositeFileListFilter<LsEntry> buildRemoteFileFilter() {
        CompositeFileListFilter<LsEntry> addFilters = new ChainFileListFilter<LsEntry>()
                .addFilters(
                        new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(buildRegexFileFilter()),
                        new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "TEST"));
        return addFilters;
    }
    
    private CompositeFileListFilter<File> buildLocalFileFilter() {
        CompositeFileListFilter<File> addFilters = new ChainFileListFilter<File>()
                .addFilters(
                        new RegexPatternFileListFilter(buildRegexFileFilter()),
                        new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
        return addFilters;
    }
    
    private Pattern buildRegexFileFilter() {
        String date = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
        final String regex1 = "^TEST[0-9]{2}_[A-Z0-9_]{7}"+date+"[0-9]+_DATA\\.(TXT)$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex1);
        return pattern;
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I gave you an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400613/getting-dynamic-file-in-spring-integration-flow. There is just no reason to be tied to the current day via that regexp. And yes: it cannot be changed. You may implement some other filter to compare the name of the file with the current day, but that's not relevant to regexp.